# jQuery only allow one version

Tags: jquery, external-script

I have a third party script that is including jquery (which causes things to break).  I am using 1.6 version and the external script is using an older version.

How can I force that only one version of jquery is loaded and it is the version I have on the page not the one loaded externally?

Comment: Usually, just including your version after the plugin will overwrite any changes they make to the global namespace, including `jQuery` and `$`.

Comment: Well, I don't know if that is safe to use a newer version of jQuery with an older version since you may break things in the third party script by using jQuery 1.6.  Is it okay to load both versions or do you just want 1.6?

Comment: I just want 1.6. I will just have to test that it won't break the third party js.

Comment: Someone recommended using $$ for my scripts to make sure there isnt conflicts, but still have both load (slower, but maybe more robust)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would recommend.  In general updating jQuery is fine but I have seen some freak bugs occur. The only way to stop the script from loading the older version of jquery is to patch the 3rd party source.

Comment: I do not like the idea of loading two versions of jQuery... it just seems redundantly sloppy.  The best solution would be to update or replace the out-of-date plugin so that everything uses the same version of jQuery.  Otherwise, the answer below by **stefgosselin** seems pretty solid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy to do, using jquery.noConfict();

```
<script src='jquery-1.6.js'></script>
<script>
var jq16 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src='jquery-1.4.2.js'></script>
<script>
var jq142 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

You can then have functions use the $() namespace as so:

```
 (function($) {
$('<button>Use jQuery 1.4.2</button>')
    .click(function() {
        alert('Top: ' + $(this).offset().top + '\n' +
            'jQuery: ' + $.fn.jquery);
    })
    .appendTo('body');
})(jq142);
```

There is a more detailed example and a few extra tips on [this page](http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/10/03/using-multiple-versions-of-jquery/).

Answer (score 1):

USE [.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) instead?
**Ex:**
I have this into my `<head>` inside the HTML document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict()
jQuery16 = jQuery
</script>
```

And into my jQ script I call it like:

```
jQuery16(document).ready(function($){


$('.textarea').text(' Hello World! ');



});
```

Doing so I'm shure that MY script will not interfer with an external that uses some other / older version of jQuery.