# Bundling javascript with a library

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written some JS snippets that webmasters are required to insert into their website to enable various features.

My code depends on jQuery.

My questions are:

- What's the best way of bundling jQuery with my code, instead of the normal `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`, which seems like a bad idea.
- How can I make sure any jQuery I import doesn't interfere with any jQuery they might already have on their site?

Comment: use webpack to bundle your js code and jquery library and export it to your site. webpack allows to use different namespace to invoke jquery functions :)

Comment: May this "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272181/jquery-only-allow-one-version" kann help you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this eaxmple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>        
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
   var $x = jQuery.noConflict();
   alert("Version: "+$x.fn.jquery);
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   var $y = jQuery.noConflict();
   alert("Version: "+$y.fn.jquery);
</script>
<script>        
        alert("First Version: " + $x.fn.jquery + ", Second Version: " + $y.fn.jquery);
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

try to set a "namespace" for your jquery and use it in your scripts